# Perl - compares array elements sentences with a variable

Tags: arrays, perl, grep

I use grep to return unmatched array between temporaryF file and arrayWarning

```
my @c =grep!${{map{$_,1}@temporaryF}{$_},@arrayWarning;
```

Inside @c there are alot of lines for example:

```
Sun Sep 30 00:05:55 fibre channel DENY forever
Sun Sep 30 00:06:55 fibre channel ROOT cause
Sun Sep 30 00:08:55 fibre channel ROOT cause 
Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT cause  
Sun Sep 30 00:20:55 fibre channel DANN 
Sun Sep 30 00:30:55 fibre channel DANN
```

as you can see ROOT occurs 3 times in @c. How can I iterate through @c to output only the latest occurrence of ROOT -> Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT
and not the other repeated lines.

so it will become:

```
Sun Sep 30 00:05:55 fibre channel DENY forever  
Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT cause  
Sun Sep 30 00:30:55 fibre channel DANN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Note**: this is an extension of the answer of @RobEarl - so if you like it, please make sure to give him credits, too!

The point here is to store the line count too, to make sure the output can be ordered.

### Long version

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

# store (with count)
my $count  = 0;
my %latest = map {
    my $source = (split /\s+/ => $_)[6];
    $source => {count => $count++, string => $_};
} <DATA>;

# output
print $_->{string} for sort {$a->{count} <=> $b->{count}} values %latest;

__DATA__
Sun Sep 30 00:05:55 fibre channel DENY forever
Sun Sep 30 00:06:55 fibre channel ROOT cause
Sun Sep 30 00:08:55 fibre channel ROOT cause 
Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT cause  
Sun Sep 30 00:20:55 fibre channel DANN 
Sun Sep 30 00:30:55 fibre channel DANN
```

**Output**:

```
Sun Sep 30 00:05:55 fibre channel DENY forever
Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT cause  
Sun Sep 30 00:30:55 fibre channel DANN
```

Feels a little bit like the [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

### One-liner version

This is an excellent example for a task that can be accomplished by a simple oneliner with perl's powerful [interpreter switches](http://p3rl.org/perlrun):

```
$ perl -nale '$l{$F[6]}={c=>$c++,s=>$_};END{print$_->{s}for sort{$a->{c}<=>$b->{c}}values%l}'
Sun Sep 30 00:05:55 fibre channel DENY forever
Sun Sep 30 00:06:55 fibre channel ROOT cause
Sun Sep 30 00:08:55 fibre channel ROOT cause 
Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT cause  
Sun Sep 30 00:20:55 fibre channel DANN 
Sun Sep 30 00:30:55 fibre channel DANN
```

Output:

```
Sun Sep 30 00:05:55 fibre channel DENY forever
Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT cause  
Sun Sep 30 00:30:55 fibre channel DANN
```

Comment: Hello, could you please post some information about that `__XYZ__` language construct you used in your code? Does it have some name so I could search it? I've never seen it before.

Comment: Hi @duri, I'm not sure if this is the best perldoc to start with, but I found something about it in [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Special-Literals). It was just a handy way to store both the program and its input data in one script file. :)

Comment: thank you this works only if the warning words are after (split /\s+/ => $_)[6];
But how to change it to substr($_,20)? I couldnt seem to work this in your coding.

Comment: @momokjaaaaa Please find a way to show your complete not-working code! :)

Comment: never mind I got it. I changed it to my $source = (substr($_,20)); before this it was my $source = (substr($_,20) => $_); that's why.

Comment: By the way @memowe how do you put all the values of $_->{string} for sort {$a->{count} <=> $b->{count}} values %latest; into a variable?

Comment: @momokjaaaaa `my @strings = map $_->{string} => sort {...} values %latest;` - HTH :)

Answer (score 3):

Use a hash with ROOT/DENY/DANN as the key:

```
my %latest = map { (split(" "))[6] => $_ } @c;
```

Assuming `@c` is ordered by date, `values %latest` will contain:

```
Sun Sep 30 00:10:55 fibre channel ROOT cause
Sun Sep 30 00:05:55 fibre channel DENY forever
Sun Sep 30 00:30:55 fibre channel DANN
```

Comment: The ordering of `@c` has no (defined) influence on the order of `values %latest` because hashes aren't ordered.

Comment: @memowe no but it does influence the content

Comment: Nevermind, you're right, that only the "latest" occurence of `ROOT` for example will survive. However, the values list isn't ordered by date as one might assume.

Comment: I added an extension of this answer with sortable output.

Comment: @memowe, looks good. I was thinking of getting the order from `@c` (`grep` at the end) but preserving it through the hash probably makes more sense.