# How to get first n key-value pairs from a hash table in Perl

Tags: perl, hash

I'm very new to perl so I searched for some time but still get the answer. I want to get first 100 pairs from a hash table but don't know how to do that. To get each pair from a hash table, we can do something like:

```
foreach my $term (keys %hashtable)
{
    do something regarding $hashtable{$term} here
}
```

But how to get first 100 pairs out of it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: I recommend removing the word "first" from this question.  Hash tables are not ordered so there is no concept of "first".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm new to Perl too and may be there is more elegant solution, but you can do the following:

```
my $i = 0;
foreach my $term (keys %hashtable) {
    ...
    do something regarding $hashtable{$term} here
    ...

    last if ($i++) == 100;    
}
```

Comment: Note that this gets the "first" 101 pairs, not 100.

Comment: ok, I corrected it a bit ... probably this will work fine. If you need a sorted order you can sort the keys by using `sort { $a cmp $b} keys %hashtable`

Answer (score 8):

Another way:

```
my %hash100 = (%hashtable)[0..199];
while ( my ($key, $value) = each %hash100 ) {
    ...
}
```

or:

```
for my $key ( (keys %hashtable)[0..99] ) {
    my $value = $hashtable{$key};
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please, could you explain why in the first approach you wrote, it's needed to use `[0..2*N-1]` instead of `[0..N-1]`, like in your second approach? Thank you

Comment: @IvánRodríguezTorres a hash in list context produces a list of key,value,key,value...  and assigning to a hash also expects such a list.  If for 100 keys, you need 200 elements in this list.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you for clarify

Answer (score 7):

Note that there is nothing like *the first 100* pairs from a hash since a hash has no particular order.

Another solution that should protect your from off-by-one errors:

```
for my $i (1 .. 100) {
    my ($key, $value) = each %hashtable;
    print "$key => $value\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding that. I want to get the first 100 pairs out of it because I firstly sort the hash table by value.

Comment: @lam619 You cannot sort hash by value (or anything else). Hash is unordered, period. What you can do is sort out the keys, then iterate over this sorted array.

Comment: @raina77ow I did something like `foreach my $term (sort {$scores{$b} <=> $scores{$a}}keys %scores)` and I think it orders the hash table in descending order numerically by the value. Does it have any problem? Thanks.

Comment: @Iam619 With all due respect, it looks like we have a classic XY problem here. You've got a hash of scores (probably in 'player' => 'score') format, and now you need to print the top 100 players along with their scores, is that so?

Comment: @raina77ow Yes kind of. Is there any problem with this code? If so, please point it out. Thanks!

Comment: @Iam619 There's nothing wrong with this particular code: if you already have this hash of players' scores, the `for ((sort {...} keys)[0..99] )` part is pretty straightforward. The 'X' here is about the source of this hash: I just can't help wondering why it returns such information in form of a hash (unordered structure), and not an array (ordered structure).

Comment: @raina77ow I guess it is because I still need the key instead of just the value? Does the array order everything automatically? If so, I still need to associate the key to the value so I used a hash table..Is there better way to do it with an array?

Comment: @Iam619 The problem here is, that hashes *lose* any order because they aren't ordered by definition. I recently answered a question about a hash structure with an additional hash level to "remember" the input order [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111805/perl-compares-array-elements-sentences-with-a-variable/13112850#13112850).

Comment: **Perl has never guaranteed any ordering of the hash keys**, please read [Hash Randomisation](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/perl-5.18.2/pod/perl581delta.pod#Hash_Randomisation)